# Python 3 can not pickle dump

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have been working on a project where I store some values in a tree data type.(I have used liblarch liblary's tree) and now I am trying to store these data in locally using Python pickle.

However now I get this error and can not find a solution about the problem. Can anyone suggest anything about this? Here is the error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: did you check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239281/getting-typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-lock-objects)?

Comment: I did check the issue that you suggest but cant seem to find a solution for my problem. Btw I'm not allowed to share any code but I think I gave enough information about the problem. Thanks for the replies.